# Programmatically include snippet or asset on template page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I want to include a file on the product.liquid template and on the 'Thank You' page of the checkout.

As far as I know, I can't use ScriptTags because I want to use liquid variables on these pages. The liquid content may occasionally be specific to the template,

such as:

```
{{product.id}} or {{checkout.line_items}}
```

Currently on app installation I'm placing a liquid snippet this way:

```
ShopifyAPI::Asset.create(key: "snippets/name.liquid", src: "myserver/myfile.liquid")
```

This file can be included by a store developer by inserting this on a template page:

```
{% include 'name' %}
```

Is there a way to do this, or something to the same effect, programatically? This can either be accomplished on installation of the app (at the same time the snippet is created), or when the theme page is loaded.

Comment: Hey man!! where did you add the code to create the snippet as it should be created only once right?

Comment: Hey, i went back and looked at my old repo for you. Our app had an auth flow on the admin end, and at the end of the flow i would check if i had added them using a column in the Shop database. `shop_domain = params[:shop]`
`@shopObject = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)` then only add the script tags if @shobObject.added_scripttags == false. Just add that field with a migration

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am adding this snippet when the recurring charge is accepted for the first time. I think it will do the trick. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, however this is what I do to add snippets as you've described.

```
{% if product.id == '13' %}
   {% include 'name' %}
{% endif $}
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
{% if template == 'index' or template == 'collection.HANDLE' %}
    {% include 'name' %}
{% endif %}
```

*Note: HANDLE would be replaced with your collection handle/name.

Comment: This not what I mean. First of all, I don't want to instruct store owners to go to their template files and write a liquid include statement themselves. Secondly, liquid include statements do not work on the checkout "Thank You" page when place in the "Additional Content and Scripts" box.

Comment: Ah, I believe I understand. You want to add the include using the API?
If so, this might be useful:

https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/asset#update
The section listed as "Change an existing liquid template's value"